# Timepicker - Dependencies between dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I have a form that allow me to add hours of travel and work times.
For example, I can tell when I leave the company and at what time I arrived at the customer and then the other way around. And also for work hours, at what time I started working, what time I went to lunch and the same for the afternoon.
The question here is that I am not doing any validations between dropdowns.

For example I can say that it leaves at `09:00` and I arrived at `08:00`. When I select `09:00` the next dropdown should load starting at `09:30` for example.

I can add several days, so I use the the tag name like this `hour-day-1[]`.

How can I create this kind of dependencies with timepicker?

This is my html form:

```
    <tr>
       <td><label>Day 1:</label></td>
       <td><label>Go</label></td>
       <td class="@if ($errors->has('hour-day-1[1]')) has-error @endif">
          {!! Form::text('hour-day-1[1]', old('hour-day-1[1]'), ['class' => 'form-control travelGoStartHour', 'placeholder'=> '']) !!}
       </td>
       <td class="@if ($errors->has('hour-day-2[1]')) has-error @endif">
          {!! Form::text('hour-day-2[1]', old('hour-day-2[1]'), ['class' => 'form-control travelGoEndHour', 'placeholder'=> '']) !!}
       </td>
       <td>
          <label>Back</label>
       </td>
       <td class="@if ($errors->has('hour-day-3[1]')) has-error @endif">
          {!! Form::text('hour-day-3[1]', old('hour-day-3[1]'), ['class' => 'form-control travelBackStartHour', 'placeholder'=> '']) !!}
       </td>
       <td class="@if ($errors->has('hour-day-4[1]')) has-error @endif">
          {!! Form::text('hour-day-4[1]', old('hour-day-4[1]'), ['class' => 'form-control travelBackEndHour', 'placeholder'=> '']) !!}
       </td>
       <td>
         <i class="icon-plus-circled add-new-day-travel" title="Add New Day" data-id="1"></i>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

This is the way how I initialize timepicker:

```
    $('.travelGoStartHour').timepicker({
      'minTime': '8:00',
      'maxTime': '20:00',
      'showDuration': true,
      'timeFormat': 'HH:mm:ss'
    });
    $('.travelGoEndHour').timepicker({
      'minTime': '8:00',
      'maxTime': '20:00',
      'showDuration': true,
      'timeFormat': 'HH:mm:ss'
    });
    $('.travelBackStartHour').timepicker({
      'minTime': '8:00',
      'maxTime': '20:00',
      'showDuration': true,
      'timeFormat': 'HH:mm:ss'
    });
    $('.travelBackEndHour').timepicker({
      'minTime': '8:00',
      'maxTime': '20:00',
      'showDuration': true,
      'timeFormat': 'HH:mm:ss'
    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

```
$('.travelGoStartHour').on('changeTime', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $('.travelGoEndHour').option('minTime', selectedValue);
});

$('.travelBackStartHour').on('changeTime', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $('.travelBackEndHour').option('minTime', selectedValue);
});
```

Comment: ok, works! And how can I add more 30 minutes to next dropdown? @bastos.sergio

Comment: alter the `selectedValue` to whatever you want (for instance if `selectedValue` is `9:00` parse  the nine out and concatenate the `':30'` to the output)